# Permitir abrir só uma div

Tags: javascript

Código para chamar as divs:

```
<input style="float: right;" class="botao1" onclick="addRisco()" value="Adicionar Risco"/>
  </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
        </fieldset>
<div id="riscos">

</div>
<fieldset class="grupo">
    <table width="100%" class="campo" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
        <td>
 <input style="float: right;" class="botao1" onclick="addRisco1()" value="Acção"/>
  </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
<div id="riscos1">

</div>
```

Com esta função sempre que clico no botão abre uma div:

```
function addRisco(){ 
$("#riscos").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform").html()+"</div>"); 
} 
function addRisco1(){ 
$("#riscos1").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform1").html()+"</div>"); 
}
```

Mas pretendo que a função só permita abrir uma vez a div.

Comment: Como você chama as funções addRisco() e addRisco1(). Insira o código da chamada delas.

Comment: Você pode colocar um id na `div` e verificar se já existe antes de fazer o `append`,uma solução simples, o que acha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando se utiliza o método  `one()`, a função é executada apenas uma vez para cada elemento.

> coloque um id para cada elemento

```js
$("#botao").one("click", function(){
    $("#riscos").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform").html()+"</div>"); 
}); 

$("#botao1").one("click", function(){
    $("#riscos1").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform1").html()+"</div>"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="botao" style="float: right;" class="botao1" value="Adicionar Risco"/>
  </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
        </fieldset>
<div id="riscos">

</div>
<fieldset class="grupo">
    <table width="100%" class="campo" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
        <td>
 <input id="botao1" style="float: right;" class="botao1" value="Acção"/>
  </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
<div id="riscos1">

</div>
```

> Com a função `one()` não é necessário verificar se `tem Filhos`ou seja, elementos descendentes do elemento selecionado

```js
$("#botao").one("click", function(){
    $("#riscos").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform").html()+"</div>"); 
}); 

$("#botao1").one("click", function(){
    $("#riscos1").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform1").html()+"</div>"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="grupo">
<input  id="botao" style="float: right;" class="botao1" value="Adicionar Risco"/>

<div id="riscos"></div>

<br><br>
 <input id="botao1" style="float: right;" class="botao1" value="Acção"/>

<div id="riscos1"></div>
```

[**.one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Bacana, não conhecia esse método!

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma:

```
function addRisco(){
    var temFilhos = $("#riscos").find("div").length > 0;

    if(!temFilhos){
        $("#riscos").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform").html()+"</div>"); 
    }
} 

function addRisco1(){ 
    var temFilhos = $("#riscos1").find("div").length > 0;

    if(!temFilhos){
        $("#riscos1").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform1").html()+"</div>"); 
    }
}
```

Dica: Passe a ter o costume de identar o seu código, mesmo quando escreve códigos de teste, com o tempo fará isso naturalmente. Ajuda muito a visualizar a hierarquia do html, e facilita muito na manutenção.